# Can you just use one side of Airpods and leave the other side at home?

Tags: airpods

Because I usually just use one side of the Airpods, so that I am aware of the environment whenever I exercise or in a cafe, can only one side of the Airpods be used independently, while the other one is left at home?

So if one side of the Airpods is lost for some reason, you can still use the other side independently?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, AirPods can be used independently in only one ear.

I use only one AirPod the majority of the time. Great for mono podcasts and for environmental awareness as you're walking around.

Comment: Though I would like to add that taking the case with you has the undeniable advantage that you actually can reload your pods when on the go.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg "can reload your pods when on the go" ... you mean "recharging it"?

Comment: @nopole Sorry, not a native speaker and one coffee short of brain working properly.